# Not understand the result hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript

Why true? How method foo written in the object?

```
Object.prototype.foo = function(obj) {
    for(var i in obj) this[i] = obj[i];
};

var obj = {a: 1};

var testObj = {};

testObj.foo(obj)

alert( testObj.hasOwnProperty("foo") );
```

Comment: A 10 seconds' search for: [has own property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) and [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) won't break your routine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `for ... in` loop iterates through *all* of the visible properties of the target objects, including those on its prototype chain.

If you only want to transfer the "own" properties of the source object, you can add a test:

```
Object.prototype.foo = function(obj) {
    for(var i in obj) 
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i))
        this[i] = obj[i];
};
```

Comment: Similarly, quite out of my head :)

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov ?? What does that mean?

Comment: This is Google Translate :)

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov ah OK :)

Comment: Pointy, how old you are practice of programming?

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov I started in about 1980 :)

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov The pale man is at least 256 years old to my humble estimations. Probably a grandson of Dracula.

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov He'll never admit. The vampires are undercover.

Comment: @Vidul ha ha - Yes, Aleksandr, I'm pretty old. I've only been doing web programming for about 15 years however.

Comment: OMG. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The portrait from which my avatar is taken was painted in the early 1500s (around 1435 I think), and it's one of the very few paintings from that time in Northern Europe that can be positively tied to a particular painter. The painting hangs in the National Gallery in London, and I very strongly recommend a visit. It is a strange subject but the painting is astonishingly beautiful.

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov I can only recommend this guy. Pretty good he is :)

Comment: @Vidul, I know. He often helped me.

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov However, keep in mind that he comes from 1500. Never approach him physically without silver and garlic in the pocket!

Comment: @Vidul, ok, I remember.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `testObj.foo(obj)`, the `foo` method is called with the `this` value set to `testObj`.

Therefore, this code...

```
for(var i in obj) this[i] = obj[i];
```

...adds the enumerable (own or inherited) properties of `obj` as own properties of `this` (`testObj` in this case).

And `foo` is an enumerable (inherited) property of `obj`, so it is added to `testObj`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Object.prototype.foo = function(obj) {
    for(var i in obj) this[i] = obj[i];
};

var obj = {a: 1};

var testObj = {};

alert( testObj.hasOwnProperty("foo") ); // false

testObj.foo(obj)

alert( testObj.hasOwnProperty("foo") ); // true
```

As you can see the foo method is attached to the object after `foo` is called.

Why? Because `for..in` will iterate through all keys which are enumerable, regardless if they live on the object or on one of its prototypes.

```
Object.prototype.foo = function(obj) {
   for ( var i in obj ) {
      console.log(i, '=', obj.hasOwnProperty(i)); // foo=false
   }
};
```

The 'foo' method is enumerable, you can check using

```
Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable("foo") // true
```

How do you make a property non-enumerable?

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'foo', {
  'configurable': true, // can be removed using 'delete' operator
  'enumerable': false, // will not show up in a for..in iteration
  'writable': true, // can be overridden
  'value': function () {
     for ( var key in this ) {
          console.log(key, '=', this.hasOwnProperty(key));
     }
   }
});
```

Just in case you were wondering:

```
Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable("hasOwnProperty") // false
Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable("propertyIsEnumerable") // false
```